# External USB device attached to Android phone

Tags: android, usb

I would like to ask you if is it possible to read data from attached external USB devices? In my case I wonder if I can attach some signal sensor and fetch data via USB to my application. How can data transfer be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Android provides [USBHost](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) API. You can read device info and open read/write connections.